# ModuleNotFoundError when launching a python file from another

Tags: python, module, os.system

I am currently learning Python and I work on a project where I need a launcher to launch a series of the same script.

So, I have the launcher calling my other script, and I need the second script to import modules for it to work. But then I get the infamous **ModuleNotFound**: no module named "". When I launch the file myself, it works properly as intended and the module is found.

**LAUNCHER**

```
i=0  
while i<1000:
 print('Creating file number '+str(i)+'')
 os.system('C:\\Users\\Gauthier\\Desktop\\file.py')
 time.sleep(int(frequency))
 print('File number '+str(i)+' created')
 i+=1
```

I guess that must be a miscomprehension on my side, but after reading tens of questions on stackeoverflow and other forums, the official documentation and some tutorials, I can't find the proper way to import a module in a script which is itself launched by another file.

As **file.py** requests data from APIs, I cannot just read the script with

```
exec(open('file.py').read())
```

because I need multiple instances of the same script to be launched at the same time.

I am sorry if I missed something obvious, but it's been days -- I've uninstalled Python multiple times, tried a lot of different ways to call a file from another-- but I finally came here to ask for help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simple work around could be that you can add the path in

```
sys.path.append('/usr/lib64/python2.7/')
sys.path.append('<path to your modules>')
```

and then import your packages.

A similar statement can be used as many times and can be used to import your modules as well.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I was being desperate about this. Guess I need to understand imports better.